# ffmpeg Major_Brand and Minor_Version

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, plex

I've found that certain videos I encode are unplayable on my LG TV streaming via Plex. I think the issue may have something to do with the Major_Brand and Minor_Version. Files that play are Major_Brand=mp42 and Minor_Version=0. Files that don't are isom and 512. I can use the command "-brand mp42" and change the Major_Brand but the Minor_Version stays 512 (and the video still doesn't play). How do I change the Minor_Version?

```
C:\Users\Michael\Videos\Recode>ffprobe -i Does.mp4
ffprobe version git-2020-03-12-675bb1f Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.100 / 56. 42.100
  libavcodec     58. 75.100 / 58. 75.100
  libavformat    58. 41.100 / 58. 41.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.100 /  7. 77.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000013da7bbb040] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Does.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomhvc1
    creation_time   : 2021-07-29T02:03:55.000000Z
    encoder         : DVDFab 12.0.4.0
    title           : Does
  Duration: 01:16:39.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1909 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 1392 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-29T02:03:55.000000Z
      encoder         : HEVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 511 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-29T02:03:55.000000Z
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-29T02:03:55.000000Z
    Stream #0:3: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x750 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:3], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
Unsupported codec with id 100359 for input stream 2


C:\Users\Michael\Videos\Recode>ffprobe -i doesnt.mp4
ffprobe version git-2020-03-12-675bb1f Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.100 / 56. 42.100
  libavcodec     58. 75.100 / 58. 75.100
  libavformat    58. 41.100 / 58. 41.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.100 /  7. 77.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025b4377b040] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'doesnt.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    date            : 2021
    encoder         : DVDFab
    title           : Doesn't
  Duration: 01:49:15.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2329 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1869 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2: Video: bmp, bgra, 640x360, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
```

Comment: Copy and paste the complete outputs from `ffprobe -show_streams -show_format video-that-works.mp4` & `ffprobe -show_streams -show_format video-that-does-not-work.mp4`

Comment: As requested, data added to original post. You can see I was using DVDFab for both. The difference, other than mp42/isom is that the mp42 had a folder structure and so Fab used "Ripper", whereas isom was just a file and so Fab used "Converter". I usually use Fab because it gives me metadata and nice poster thumbnails but I use ffmpeg for the files Fab won't do. However, now I'm getting the same won't play issue with ffmpeg. Still, many ffmpeg files do play and they are isom. I'm lost here.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i doesnt.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -brand mp42 -tag:v hvc1 -movflags +faststart test.mp4`. I don't see an option to set minor_version. Also, get a new ffmpeg at gyan.dev. Yours is more than a year old.

Comment: I will try that. Btw, I did download the latest and it failed to update over the last; I even deleted the old and pasted the new folder - that resulted in ffmpeg not working.

Comment: Okay, I tried it but it didn't work. I got the following error:
[mp4 @ 000002175dc1b2c0] Tag hvc1 incompatible with output codec id '7' (mp4v)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input